# Как добавить атрибут selected для тега <option>

Tags: jquery, ajax

Отправляю данные аяксом, и возвращаю массив. Как сделать, чтобы был выделен тег `<option>`?  Имею ввиду, как добавить атрибут `selected` для тега `<option>`

```
$('#save').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "url..",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        },
        data: {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            value: $('#value').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#results').append($("<option>", {value: data[0], text: data[1] + ' : ' + data[2]})).attr("selected","selected");
            $('#spec-cont').find('input[type=text]').val('');
        },
        error:  function(xhr, str){
            alert('Хьюстон! У нас проблемы!');
        }
    });
});
```

Разметка

```
<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="results" name="specifications[]" >
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавлять надо не атрибут:

```
.prop('selected',true);
```